# After upgrading to 2015.04, VirtualBox crashes at Windows VM start, nothing in log

Tags: upgrade, virtualbox, 15.04

I have many Linux and Windows virtual machines, they were fine on a Ubuntu 2014.04 host.

I recently updated the host to 2015.04, and all of the Windows VMs have stopped working. All Linux VMs are fine. Both VirtualBox 4.3.26 from the Ubuntu repository and VirtualBox 4.3.28 from the project's website have the problem.

When I start a Windows VM, it runs for about 10 seconds to a minute, with the Windows 7 "Staring Windows" logo animation, and then all of a sudden the virtualbox process dies.

```
$ VirtualBox --startvm "win7pro32bit blabla"
Segmentation fault
$ echo $?
139
```

The log file does not show any particular problem:

```
00:00:09.228641 AHCI#0: Reset the HBA
00:00:09.257329 Guest Additions information report: Version 4.2.10 r84104 '4.2.10'
00:00:09.257467 Guest Additions information report: Interface = 0x00010004 osType = 0x00037000 (32-bit)
00:00:09.257586 Guest Additions capability report: (0x0 -> 0x0) seamless: no, hostWindowMapping: no, graphics: no
00:00:09.257629 UIMachineLogicNormal::sltCheckForRequestedVisualStateType: Requested-state=0, Machine-state=5
00:00:09.257715 UIMachineLogicNormal::sltCheckForRequestedVisualStateType: Requested-state=0, Machine-state=5
00:00:09.257755 Guest reported fixed hypervisor window at 0008f800000 (size = 0xc00000, rc = VINF_SUCCESS)
00:00:09.257867 UIMachineLogicNormal::sltCheckForRequestedVisualStateType: Requested-state=0, Machine-state=5
00:00:12.037877 Guest Log: VBoxMP::VBoxDrvFindAdapter: using HGSMI
00:00:12.189515 OHCI: Software reset
00:00:12.189673 OHCI: USB Reset
00:00:12.245305 OHCI: USB Operational
00:00:12.257475 EHCI: Hardware reset
00:00:12.257698 EHCI: USB Operational
```

([full log](https://gist.github.com/nicolas-raoul/4831eb095cb593eb3399))

Is there some upgrade step that I am not aware of?
For instance some plugin installation or configuration that needs to be performed?

Comment: This may apparently be a Windows issue - `00:00:09.257329 Guest Additions information report: Version 4.2.10 r84104 '4.2.10'` could indicate a possible issue from out-dated Guest Additions in the Windows VM but I can't really tell you how to install these in a non-booting Windows. Try to disable 3D acceleration, USB, shared folders in the settings, or boot in fail-safe mode may be worth a try.

Comment: @Takkat: Exactly! I run `VirtualBox -startvm` on command line, that's why I did not get the extensions update dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved the problem:

1. Uninstall VirtualBox
2. Download the latest VirtualBox release at https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads
3. Run the GUI once to update extensions
4. Run as usual

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after updating Virtualbox from 4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5 to 4.3.34-dfsg-1+deb8u1ubuntu1.14.04.1, concretely the following packages: virtualbox, virtualbox-dkms and virtualbox-qt.

I got to start my VM after disabling USB2.0 (EHCI).

To solve the problem and use your VM with USB2.0, what I did is to update the Oracle VM Virtualbox ExtensionPack to the same version: 4.3.34r104062

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall dkms
```

and then run vboxdrv, and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Thanks! I ran `sudo apt-get install --reinstall dkms` then `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv restart` then retried, same problem unfortunately.